# Storing form values from a form in a session in coldfusion

Tags: forms, session, coldfusion

I have these form values I'm trying capture in a session:

```
prop_zip
prop_st
address
city
fname
lname
email
pri_phone_1
pri_phone_2
pri_phone_3
```

Here is my session code:

```
<cfapplication name="qsErrorVals" clientmanagement="yes" sessionmanagement="yes" sessiontimeout="#createTimeSpan(0,0,360,0)#">
<cflock timeout="120" name="#session.sessionID#" type="exclusive">
    <cfset session.prop_st="#prop_st#">
    <cfset session.prop_zip="#prop_zip#">
    <cfset session.address="#address#">
    <cfset session.fname="#fname#">
    <cfset session.lname="#lname#">
    <cfset session.email="#email#">
    <cfset session.pri_phone_1="#pri_phone_1#">
    <cfset session.pri_phone_2="#pri_phone_2#">
    <cfset session.pri_phone_3="#pri_phone_3#">  
</cflock>
```

So far, I can only save two of the variables from the form:

```
prop_zip
prop_st
```

The rest I'm having trouble with saving the form values to the session.  I've defined the variables I want to store in the session before creating the session and I've tried using this code:

```
<cfset session.email="#form.email#">
etc...
```

Still I can only save the two variables I mentioned.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer specifically without looking at all of your code but hopefully this example will help.

- The `cfapplication` tag should go in an Application.cfm or Application.cfc file.
- The session code should most likely be placed in another file.
- I'd recommend specifying a `scope` attribute of `session` in the `cflock` tag.

Application.cfm file:

```
<cfapplication name="qsErrorVals" clientmanagement="yes" sessionmanagement="yes" sessiontimeout="#createTimeSpan(0,0,360,0)#">
```

ErrorVals.cfm or whatever you want to call the file:

```
<cfparam name="form.prop_st" default="NY" > <!--- I've added default data for testing --->
<cfparam name="form.prop_zip" default="12345" >
<cfparam name="form.address" default="1st Main St." >
<cfparam name="form.fname" default="John" >
<cfparam name="form.lname" default="Doe" >
<cfparam name="form.email" default="me@domain.com" >
<cfparam name="form.pri_phone_1" default="123-123-1234" >
<cfparam name="form.pri_phone_2" default="123-123-1234" >
<cfparam name="form.pri_phone_3" default="123-123-1234" >
<cfscript>
    prop_st = trim(form.prop_st); // validate, trim, etc.
    prop_zip = trim(form.prop_zip);
    address = trim(form.address );
    fname = trim(form.fname );
    lname = trim(form.lname );
    email = trim(form.email);
    pri_phone_1 = trim(form.pri_phone_1);
    pri_phone_2 = trim(form.pri_phone_2);
    pri_phone_3 = trim(form.pri_phone_3);
</cfscript>

<cflock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="10" >
    <cfset session.prop_st = prop_st>
    <cfset session.prop_zip = prop_zip>
    <cfset session.address= address>
    <cfset session.fname= fname>
    <cfset session.lname= lname>
    <cfset session.email= email>
    <cfset session.pri_phone_1= pri_phone_1>
    <cfset session.pri_phone_2= pri_phone_2>
    <cfset session.pri_phone_3= pri_phone_3>  
</cflock>

<cfdump var="#session#">
```

Answer (score 4):

Eh, I usually take the easy way out.  In addition to the recommendations about cfapplication, scoping and paraming form vars in [Micah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980680/21960), I'd copy the whole form struct into session.

```
 session.theForm = structCopy(form);
```